# Which Sphinx code-block language to use for JSON

Tags: pygments, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx to document a web service.  I would like to show a formatted JSON web response using the code-block directive, which Spinx does via Pygments, but JSON doesn't have a syntax highlighter in Pygments.  What language do you suggest I specify instead?  HTML?  JavaScript?

```
.. code-block:: javascript

    {
      "name": "roger",
      "score": 100
    }
```

Answer (score 31):

I am using Sphinx 1.4.2 which includes a Pygments lexer called "*json*". This is available out-of-the-box by default. To use:

```
.. code-block:: json

    {
        "key": "value",
        "key2": "value2",
        ...
    }
```

Comment: In fact it is available starting from Pygments version 1.5. [Source](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#pygments.lexers.data.JsonLexer)

Answer (score 6):

I wasn't happy using pygments javascript for parsing JSON.  Yes, JSON can be parsed by the javascript lexer, but javascript highlighting is not very useful when applied to a JSON value.  You typically get a giant blob of undifferentiated text.

Since I couldn't find a good solution, I created a [JSON lexer for pygments](https://github.com/orb/pygments-json/).  I'm using it now for highlighting JSON in sphinx created PDF document.  It's not perfect, but the results are much more useful than with the javascript lexer.  I hope it helps.

Comment: JSON lexer for pygments is now in Pygments >= 1.5, but there seems to be a need for some Sphinx support as well, specifically you need to add a Sphinx extension that calls add_lexer (http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_lexer) for json (although this may not be necessary for latest version of Sphinx).

Answer (score 6):

Even with Sphinx 1.2b1 and Pygments 1.6, I needed to call add_lexer to get `.. code-block:: json` to do anything.  I ended up putting the following code fragment into an extension (`docs/_ext/jsonlexer.py`):

```py
def setup(app):
    # enable Pygments json lexer
    try:
        import pygments
        if pygments.__version__ >= '1.5':
            # use JSON lexer included in recent versions of Pygments
            from pygments.lexers import JsonLexer
        else:
            # use JSON lexer from pygments-json if installed
            from pygson.json_lexer import JSONLexer as JsonLexer
    except ImportError:
        pass  # not fatal if we have old (or no) Pygments and no pygments-json
    else:
        app.add_lexer('json', JsonLexer())
```

My `docs/conf.py` for Sphinx has the following to enable the extension:

```py
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('_ext'))

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions # coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = ['jsonlexer']
```

Comment: It is an excellent answer that inspired the user to build their custom style.

Answer (score 3):

JSON is JavaScript, plain and simple. JSON in fact stands for "JavaScript Object Notation".

Comment: Yep, knew that.  Just wondering if others used the javascript Pygments highlighter for JSON markup in Sphinx too or if there was another recommended language.

Comment: Gabriel's saying that JSON syntax is a strict subset of JavaScript syntax, so any proper syntax highlighter for JavaScript will also handle JSON.

Comment: Thanks Joe, and just to clarify to the OP: the JavaScript highlighter is the correct one to use, there is no JSON-specific highlighter (because JSON *is* JavaScript), and there's no better option in Sphinx for highlighting JSON.

Answer (score 2):

There is several pygment lexers dedicated to JSON highlighting provided by default with Sphinx, so you can choose one here:

http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#lexers-for-data-file-format

- pygments.lexers.data.JsonLexer (pygment v1.5+)

  For JSON data structures.

  ```
  .. code-block:: json
  ```
- pygments.lexers.data.JsonLdLexer (pygment v2.0+)

  For [JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/) linked data.

  ```
  .. code-block:: json-ld
  ```
- pygments.lexers.data.JsonBareObjectLexer (pygment v2.2+)

  For JSON data structures (with missing object curly braces).

  ```
  .. code-block:: json-object
  ```

Comment: `.. code-block:: json-object` saved my day!